# getStringExtra return NULL

Tags: android, android-intent

Here is my code, 
the first activity:

```
final String countryName = name.getText().toString();
wikiButton.setText("WIKI "+ countryName);

wikiButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(CountryDetails.this, WikiDetail.class);
      startActivity(intent);
      intent.putExtra("countryNameKey",countryName);
   }
});
```

the Second activity:

```
WebView wikiWeb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wikiWeb);
wikiWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
wikiWeb.loadUrl("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + 
     getIntent().getStringExtra("countryNameKey"));
```

the output:
[the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFHXK.png)

It always returns true, and I still have no idea after google. thx for help.

Comment: Place the putExtra call before startActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get   `countryName`  inside  your **`wikiButton.setOnClickListener()`**

```
wikiButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String countryName = name.getText().toString();

                Intent intent = new Intent(CountryDetails.this, WikiDetail.class);
                intent.putExtra("countryNameKey",countryName);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

Comment: do not need get  countryName inside your wikiButton.setOnClickListener(). just swap the startactivity and the putextra. btw, thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Put `intent.putExtra("countryNameKey",countryName);` before `startActivity(intent);`. You are starting the activity using the intent before adding the extras to it.
`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above place this line:
intent.putExtra("countryNameKey",countryName);
Before starting the activity so that the values are passed with the intent.